# iOS application size - How to reduce or download more after

Tags: iphone, ios

I am after some suggestions on how to reduce the final app size that gets submitted to apple?

Or is there any way to have stuff download after the app is isntalled? so that we can keep the app under 20 meg, but then the app downloads the rest of the program after the user has installed it and run the application?

ta
Daz

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses a lot of image resources, your application could download those images instead of building them into the application.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically possible.  Your app can access the file system, so it can make and save, and later read files.

The deal-breaker I see is that for most purposes, Apple probably wouldn't allow it.

They test the program as-is when you submit it, and they'll notice that it just sits there and tries to download a bunch of stuff from your server.  If this takes more than, say, 30 seconds, they'll reject it for usability problems.

If the content downloaded could have been bundled with the program, they'll probably have a problem with that.  If you could argue that the downloaded content changes rapidly and is a feature of your app, it might fly, but only if you keep it small..

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is totally possible.  Since it is most likely some sort of media that is causing a large file size, either images, video, or audio, you could definitely download them after the fact or supply a download button for users to add these features as "extra" content, if they are not critical to the operation of your app.

One thing to consider is that some users are not on an unlimited data plan.  So for politeness, they should know what you are doing.

Also, if you are just over the limit, you might also be able to ship the application with the resources in a zip archive and then decompress the archive in the Documents directory.

Comment: FWIW, zipping the resources is unlikely to help much. IPA archives are already ZIPped, essentially, so you're already getting that compression, and I believe the 20MB threshold applies to the downloadable IPA size.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  But I once managed to squeeze an app under the limit this way. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In many applications images take lion share of the download size, and they can be greatly reduced with [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) and [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com).

Check out this [case study **halving** download size of Tweetbot](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html) by converting images to a more efficient PNG variant.